# One text file multiple data tables using R and Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Using R/Shiny, how do I read from one text file with 3 sections into 3 separate data tables?  Each section has its own column and row names as below.  Thank you for your help!

```
     s1c1 s1c2 s1c3
s1r1 1.0  2.3  3.0
s1r2 3.3  4.5  3.6

      s2c1 s2c2 s2c3 s2c4
 s2r1 1.0  2.3  3.0  4.2
 s2r2 3.3  4.5  3.6  3.6

 etc
```

Comment: We can use readLines, then beat it into dataframes using string functions like strsplit, etc. Is this exactly how your text file looks like? By the way, as it stands this has nothing to do with shiny.

Comment: Hello,  the actual text file has "random" (no pattern such as s1c1, s2c2, etc) row and column labels.  It is possible to add a line before each section such as "section 1", "section 2", etc.  I am planning to use shiny to display and plot row(s) from each data table.  Thanks again.